# How to set URI of Image in JSON/Android

Tags: android, json, image

I am using this to send an image but it only accepts a URL. How can I set a local image?

```
JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
media.put("type", "image");
media.put("src",  "URL");
media.put("href", "http://meadjohnsonasia.com.my/mobileapp");
attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send local image like that. Either you will have to upload the image to some server and send the url to the uploaded image or upload the image directly to the server to which you are sending this json.